# If A and B are two compact convex subsets in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is this relation true for Hausdorff metric?

Tags: analysis

I want to know if the following is relation is true for non-empty, compact, convex subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Let $d_H$ denote Hausdorff metric.
\begin{equation*}
d_H(A+C,B+C)=d_H(A,B)
\end{equation*}
for any compact convex subset C.

Comment: Yes it is true. I proved this in my Honours thesis. You can find my paper on the subject [here](http://www.ybook.co.jp/online-p/JNCA/Open/17/jncav17n6p1069-oa/FLASH/index.html) and slides for an associated presentation [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwid_qroo8HdAhWLx7wKHfd4Db0QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcarma.newcastle.edu.au%2Fmeetings%2Fsims2015%2Ftalks%2Fsims2015-bendit.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3Gv5gbaYfZPj1ibBcV2z1c).

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the propositions:

> Suppose $A, B, C$ are non-empty, closed, bounded, and convex subsets of a normed linear space. Then
>   $$\overline{A + C} \subseteq \overline{B + C} \iff A \subseteq B.$$

and

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, bounded subsets of a normed linear space $X$. Then
>   $$\sup_{a \in A} \inf_{b \in B} \|a - b\| = \min \lbrace r \ge 0 : A \subseteq \overline{B + rB_X}\rbrace.$$

The first is proven in a paper by Hans Radstrom (full text can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-01/S0002-9939-1952-0045938-2/)), but also makes a nice exercise. The second is a straightforward exercise.

I call the "distance" in the second proposition, the Asymmetric Hausdorff distance, and denote it by $h(A, B)$. Then $d_H (A, B) = \min \lbrace h(A, B), h(B, A) \rbrace$. Note that it suffices to show,
$$h(A + C, B + C) = h(A, B).$$
By the first proposition, $\overline{A + C} \subseteq \overline{B + C + rB_X} \iff A \subseteq \overline{B + rB_X}$, which proves the above equality, and hence the equality you want proven.

Comment: Thank you for your  response